# Непонятная ошибка при попытке сделать файл заполненный нулями

Tags: linux

Пытаюсь сделать файл заполненный нулями но возникает непонятная ошибка. Как исправить?

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=filename bs=8M
```

Comment: какая ошибка у Вас возникает? то, что Вы пытаетесь убить основной диск? (неужели к нам вернулись пони?, если Вы понимаете о чем я)

Comment: Заменил `of=/dev/sda` на `of=filename`.

Comment: поправил ещё и метки. что бы причесать вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=filename bs=file_size count=1
```

в качестве filename Вам нужно указать имя файла ( а не имя раздела на диске). Также, так как /dev/zero бездонный, нужно уточнить размер. он как раз задается  с помощью bs и count. Их произведение как раз будет размер файла. Я взял count = 1 и теперь bs это будет как раз размер файла.

Comment: а у count нет значение по умолчанию?

Comment: dd это такая особая команда, такая теплая и ламповая, что я бы не рисковал.

Comment: Вот поэтому gui и победил :-D

Comment: gui к dd? интересно

Comment: не, консольный и графический